# Operator commutativity for inequality != in C++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have a quick question about the following expression:

```
int a_variable = 0;
if(0!=a_variable)
   a_variable=1;
```

what is the difference between "`(0 != a_variable)`" and "`(a_variable != 0)`" ?
I dont have any errors for now but is this a wrong way to use it??

Comment: To nitpick, that's commutativity, not associativity.  Associativity would be whether `(a != b) != c` was the same as `a != (b != c)` (it isn't, in general).

Comment: Actually it's symmetry. Operations are commutative (sometimes), relations are symmetric (sometimes).

Comment: @Beta:  Thanks, that's the word I was failing to think of.  Of course, if I really wanted to get nitpicky, I'd ask whether `!=` was an operation or a relation, but let's not go there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you forget the `!`, the first will give an error `(0 = a_variable)` and the second will wreak havoc `(a_variable = 0)`.

Also, with user-defined operators the second form can be implemented with a member function while the first can only be a non-member (possibly friend) function.  And it's possible, although a REALLY bad idea, to define the two forms in different ways.  Of course since `a_variable` is an `int` then there are no user-defined operators in effect in this example.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between `0 != x` and `x != 0`.

Comment: In langauges with operator overloading, you don't know. They may indeed overload the != operator for `int& rhs` to be something different... Granted, in this case it's an int, but it definitely matters!

Answer (score -1):

Any difference it may make is the order in which the arguments will be evaluated. `a != b` would conventionally evaluate `a`, then evaluate `b` and compare them, while `b != a` would do it the other way round. However, I heard somewhere that the order of evaluation is undefined in some cases.

It doesn't make a big difference with variables or numbers (unless the variable is a class with overloaded `!=` operator), but it may make a difference when you're comparing results of some function calls.

Consider

```
int x = 1;
int f() {
  x = -1;
  return x;
}
int g() {
  return x;
}
```

Assuming the operands are evaluated from left to right, then calling `(f() != g())` would yield `false`, because `f()` will evalute to `-1` and `g()` to `-1` - while `(g() != f())` would yield `true`, because `g()` will evaluate to `1` and `f()` - to `-1`.

This is just an example - better avoid writing such code in real life!

Comment: That's an invalid assumption, C++ makes no promises about the order of evaluation of operands to comparison operators.

Comment: Yes, and I pointed that. I just wanted to point out that this may be a difference for such kind of functions.

However, as far as I know, when operator `!=` is overloaded in class, then `a != b` expands to `a.operator!=(b)`, and then the left-hand operand must be evaluated first. Or am I wrong?

Comment: in `a.operator!=(b)`, both `a` and `b` are evaluated before `operator!=` is called, and there is no guarantee on whether `a` is evaluated before `b`, `b` before `a`, or the steps of each subexpression are intermingled.

Comment: order is undefined always, not "in some cases"